# Receiving Twilio Error 14103 Invalid Body on Inbound Messages

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I have an app which waits for an SMS to be received to my twilio number, and then responds with some information. However, from my understanding, the outbound SMS is not immediately sent because my app waits on a process and some other steps to be accomplished first before sending an SMS response.

When I send my incoming SMS to my Twilio number, which triggers the process, I see an error on my Twilio dashboard. The error is 14103 Invalid Body. It looks as if Twilio tries to respond to my incoming SMS immediately and because my app is not providing an immediate reply, it shows an Invalid Body (message body must be specified) error.

How can I set it so that when Twilio receives an incoming SMS, it is not waiting for a message body from my app?

Sorry if I am not being clear, I am very new to Twilio and am learning as I go. Thank you!

**Edit: Added code and a screenshot of what I'm seeing on Twilio's dashboard.**

```
<?php
include "shared.php";
if(isset($_GET['api']) || isset($_REQUEST['ApiVersion'])){
        $q=isset($_REQUEST['Body'])?$_REQUEST['Body']:$_GET['q'];

        $msg="Not authorized";
        if($user=phone2user($_REQUEST['From'])){
                if(auth_user($user,$q)){
                        $msg=mkresponse($smscbs,$q,$_REQUEST['From']);
                }else{
                        $msg="I'm sorry $user, I'm afraid I can't do that.";
                }
        }
        $arr=array('get'=>$_GET,'post'=>$_POST,'msg'=>$msg);
        file_put_contents ("data/sms.log", sprintf("%s\t%s\n",date(DATE_RSS),json_encode($arr)), FILE_APPEND);
        header("content-type: text/xml");
        printf("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Response>
    <Message>%s</Message>
</Response>",htmlspecialchars($msg));
        exit;
}

tobrowser();
echo menu();
printf ("<form action='?'><input name='q' value='%s'><input type='submit'></form>",htmlentities($_GET['q']));
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
        $q=$_GET['q'];
        $user=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        if(auth_user($user,$q)){
                printf("<h3>Run query: %s</h3>",htmlspecialchars($q));
                $r= mkresponse($smscbs,$q,123);
                $r=htmlspecialchars($r);
                printf("<pre>%s</pre>",$r);
        }else{
                echo "<h3>User $user not permitted to run query $q</h3>";
        }
}
foreach($smscbs as $key => &$value ){
        $key=preg_replace ("#^/\^?#", '', $key);
        $key=preg_replace ("#/\w*$#", '', $key);
        printf ("<a href='?q=%s'>%s</a><br/>",urlencode($key),htmlspecialchars($key));
}
?>
```

[Twilio Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8rPA.png)

Comment: It looks like your `$msg` variable is becoming unset somewhere as Twilio is just seeing it as a blank `<Message></Message>`. You are trying to build up the `$msg` it's just not coming through. What is going on in `mkresponse($smscbs,$q,$_REQUEST['From']);`? Can you get a response back from Twilio if you go down the not authorized path?